# Beamer/Beamerarticle: \mode<article> is ignored after <presentation> was set, and vice versa

Tags: beamer, include, beamerarticle

I have a problem with latex ignoring text after `\mode<presentation>` or `\mode<article>` was set.

### MWE description

I have a large document that changes modes often, and I also `\include` some more latex files. I've reduced it to the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

%\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

  1. Text without a mode being set. This should be shown
     in both presentation and article mode.

  \mode
  <presentation>
    \begin{frame}
      2. This is text inside a frame. It should only appear in presentation
    \end{frame}

  \mode
  <article>
    3. Text outside a frame. Only in article.

  \mode
  <all>
   \include{in}

\end{document}
```

With the file `in.tex` closely following the example in the beamer user guide ver. 3.26, p. 210

```
\mode*
4. This is some text outside a frame. Shouldn't be shown in presentation mode.

\begin{frame}
  5. This is text inside a frame. This is expected to show in article mode.
\end{frame}

\mode<all>
```

### Problem description

There are two cases to be considered here, compiling with `\documentclass{beamer}`, or with `\documentclass{article}` and `\usepackage{beamerarticle}`.

As I understand the relevant documentation, I should get the results as described in the body of the MWE. Instead, I get the following:

- Case "article"

  - Everything after `\mode<presentation>` seems to be ignored. I get a single page with sentence 1. Switching back to `\mode<article>` does not produce sentence 3, and the `\include` command does not seem to be processed.
- Case "beamer"

  - Sentence 1. and 2. get typest, the included file is ignored, even though it should be processed in all modes.

Experimentation with the third flavour of the `mode` command and `ignorenonframetext` has yielded the same results, please see the output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT5th.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM4q5.png) (can't include directly due to lack of reputation). I am using the second mode flavour for `\include` to work, and because I need to do fancy things like set backgrounds on some slides.

### Question

What am I missing here? As far as I can tell I have structured the document correctly. Am I misunderstanding how modes are set and processed? Is this a bug in `beamer` or `beamerarticle`? I would like to achieve the result as described in the MWE.

I am compiling this document on Arch Linux with texlive 2012, which at the moment represents  rev. 28273.

Comment: Do you have those spaces at the start of the line before `\mode` in your document? As the manual says, the line has to consist of `\mode` or `\mode*` _alone_ for 'change mode' command to work. Also, I think you want `\input` not `\include`.

Comment: @JosephWright My guess is that `\include` will be needed for a more complex document e.g. because article mode ignores `\includeonlylecture`.

Comment: @JosephWright Thank you! That was exactly what was wrong with it. I've re-read that section of the manual probably 10 times and saw the remark about how not even a comment was allowed, but that whitespace would also screw it up never even crossed my mind. If you want to convert your comment to an answer, I'll happily accept it, otherwise I'll just type it up myself.
  
@fheub I do actually have `\input` in my main document, so that I can `\include` further stuff from there. That just got lost somewhere in creating the MWE and cross-checking with the userguide, where they use `\include`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using the `\mode` command in the 'ongoing' sense (without a braced argument), the command has to be on a line on its own with no comments *or whitespace*. This is becuase the line needs to be compared 'verbatim-like' with the check value. Thus

```
Some text
\mode
  <all>
```

will work but

```
Some text
  \mode
  <all>
```

will fail. (`\mode*` is also allowed, but again with *nothing* else on the line.) The example in the question works correctly if the whitespace is tidied up.

Comment: Facing the same issue, I figured out that the mode specification must be on the next line. You cannot simply write `\mode<all>` you have to write `\mode[linebreak here]<all>`.